# Animated GIF in NSImageView

Tags: cocoa, gif, animated-gif, nsimageview

I'm using an *NSImageView* to display an animated GIF with around 80 frames, each frame being 20ms long. *NSImageView* can display the GIF animation right 'out of the box', but the problem is that it needs too much CPU, around 10% continuously (on my core i5 proc). *Instruments* shows that it spends a lot of CPU time decoding the GIF.

To make it more efficient, I have tried the following without much success:

- putting the frames inside a *QTMovie* and playing it (uses 4% for my process and another 15% for the QTKitServer process that plays the movie)
- drawing directly to the view with *CGContextDrawImage* (~5% CPU usage) - I didn't export the GIF's frames, I just created a *CGImageRef* from a 30x30px .png I had lying around.

I don't know what else to try. Subclassing *NSImageView* and somehow caching the images sounds like a good idea but, alas, I'm a beginner in Cocoa... Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `-[NSImage setCacheMode:]` with an `NSImageCacheAlways` argument?

Comment: Following your suggestion, I rewrote my NSImageView subclass and ended up with the CPU usage at about half of what it was before. I've checked and using `setCacheMode:` on the individual GIF frames that I'm cycling through doesn't make any visible difference. Your input helped me nevertheless, so thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you solve this? This is an interesting problem and I'm trying to tackle it as well. What did you change in your NSImageView subclass?

Comment: I don't have the code around anymore, but you're better off looking at NSImage/UIImage and its animation support. There also seem to be several 3rd party solutions for working with animated GIFs and NSImage. Here's one: https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif